Can you become a Catholic priest without permanently joining an organization?
It seems that in order to become a Catholic priest you have to either already be part of a religious order or essentially join the bishop's retinue of priests for that diocese.  Can anyone become a priest without a lifelong commitment of this sort?  I know that diocesan priests can join religious orders, but I assume they wouldn't want you to intentionally do that.

Would a solitary example prove this or are you looking for something in current canon law?

@PeterTurner the latter

@wmasse Generally you should give some time for people to respond to your question before choosing a correct answer.

As it doesn't qualify as a formal answer here, just as a comment: when I was ordained I have promised obedience to my bishop and any bishop that follows him. As far as I know that is the normal liturgy for ordination, you always promise obedience to the one who ordains you.


Can anyone become a priest without a lifelong commitment of this sort?

No. Ordination leaves "a spiritual and indelible mark impressed upon the soul, by which the recipient is distinguished from others, designated as a minister of Christ, and deputed and empowered to perform certain offices of Divine worship," (Summa, quoted in Holy Orders, Catholic Encyclopedia) hence to become a priest is a lifelong commitment in some form. It is either as a diocesan priest or as a religious priest, but both are formal, lifelong commitments.
The Catechism specifically mentions it cannot be temporary:

As in the case of Baptism and Confirmation this share in Christ's office is granted once for all. the sacrament of Holy Orders, like the other two, confers an indelible spiritual character and cannot be repeated or conferred temporarily (Catechism of the Catholic Church, 1582)


Correct, but sourceless.

@Wyrsa sources added

The sacrament of ordination is a permanent commitment, and generally as a rule you are within the "ranks" of the bishop who ordains you.

Canon laws §1033 through §1052 deal with "Those to be ordained" and the Requirements of them and the church.
The one specifically related to your question is Canon 1036.

For a candidate to be promoted to the order of diaconate or priesthood, he must submit to the proper Bishop or to the competent major Superior a declaration written in his own hand and signed by him, in which he attests that he will spontaneously and freely receive the sacred order and will devote himself permanently to the ecclesiastical ministry, asking at the same time that he be admitted to receive the order. (Vatican.com, The Holy See, Canon 1036)

The answer: A man who has applied for ordination has already freely committed to join the retinue of priests/deacons under the bishop.
After he is ordained he is naturally beholden uphold the commitment.

"that as part of starting the process," The part you cite is not when starting (i.e. entering seminary) but when you petition for orders, which is much later.

"unless you are commanded to go elsewhere" I don't know what you mean here.

@eques To my understanding, the written commitment must be made before ordination, during seminary you are still permitted to "change your mind" even after you finish seminary you made change your mind. But when you become a priest you cannot change your mind.

@eques commanded to go elsewhere. For example your bishop is instructed to send 2 priests to iceland, then you will be obligated to go if the bishop instructs you to. You go where the church sends you, in this case where the bishop tells you. In that case, you will be under a new bishop.

@Wrysa that was my point -- you said "starting" when it's really much later

@Wrysa except that's not ordinarily how it works. Diocesan bishops do not send their clergy on mission outside the diocese entirely without their consent.

@eques At no point did I bring up that the applicant for ordination should have had thought about what they were doing before they went to seminary either... The subject was "ordination" not "how do you become a priest step by step" :/ And from my understanding new diocesan priests get moved around quite a bit. (Canon 522 is for stability, but bishops can permit the routine change... )

@esques Look, I'm not trying to debate canon law with you, or the minutia of my phrasing. I'll edit it so that I explicitly state the subject again, instead of using gerund type pronoun.

They get moved around within the diocese. Ministry outside the diocese requires the approval of the bishop, but ordinarily doesn't occur without the consent of the individual pries.

It's okay, you can stop now. I took out that triggering phrase from the answer. It was technically offtopic from the question asked anyways.

Rather you can stop now. I was commenting because I was clarifying. If you don't like someone adding precision to what you say, then maybe this isn't the environment for you.
